# KSP: how can I get the default value of a data class property?

Tags: kotlin, annotation-processing, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have the following data class annotated with `@MyAnnotation`:

```
@MyAnnotation
data class MyDataClass(
    val foo: Boolean = true,
    val bar: Int = 123,
    val buz: String? = "abc",
)
```

From the `ClassDeclaration` I can get all the `KSPropertyDeclaration`, and I'm able to get the `simpleName` and resolve the `KSType`, but I don't know how to get the default values of each property.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's not supported by google, please check here https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/642

Comment: Please use comment for refering external links and write self contained amswers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32593824)